# Populating Spinner using ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

I have an activity in which I have to parse an XML and populate a Spinner using the parsed data.

I am done with parsing the XML. This is the method:

```
void parse_ExamList()
                    {

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                        //String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xmlContent); // getting DOM element

                        //count_questions=2;

                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_EXAMSET);
                        // looping through all item nodes <item>
                        for ( int i = 0; i < nl.getLength();i++) {


//                      while(counter< nl.getLength())
//                      {
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            //map.put(KEY_EXAMSET, parser.getValue(e, KEY_EXAMSET));
                            map.put(KEY_SETID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
                            map.put(KEY_SETNAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));
                            //Log.i("Set ID: ", parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
                            //Log.i("Set Name: ", parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));

                            menuItems.add(map);
                        }


                    }
```

If you notice you can see that **KEY_SETID** and **KEY_SETNAME** to the arraylist. I have to populate the spinner with the **KEY_SETNAME** and the **KEY_SETID** will not be shown in the spinner. But if the item is clicked then the id corresponding to the name should be acquired in order to send to the server.

I have a method to populate a spinner, like this:

```
// add items into exam list spinner dynamically
                    public void addItemsOnExamListSpinner()
                    {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("Speed Test 150(min) PO Set-01");

                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        exam_list_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    }
```

**How should I populate the spinner with the ArrayList that is obtained while parsing the XML?**

This is the **full activity**:

```
public class SpeedTestExamNameActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner exam_list_spinner;
    Button  detailsBtn;
    TextView showUser;
    String full_name;

    //variables to get response from server
    String responseBody;

    //variables required for parsing the XML
    String xmlContent=null;

 // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_EXAMSET = "ExamSet"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_SETID = "SetId";
    static final String KEY_SETNAME = "SetName";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed_test_exam_name);

        //checking internet connectivity to download list
        isOnline_downloadList();

        //Showing user full name after login
        full_name=getFromPreference("user_name");
        //textview to show user name
        showUser=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.speed_username_textView);
        showUser.setText("Welcome, "+full_name);
        //spinner
        exam_list_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.speed_examlist_spinner);
        //adding items to spinners
        addItemsOnExamListSpinner();

        // onclick details button
        detailsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speed_exam_details_button);
        detailsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this,                      
                                "Exam List Spinner: "+ String.valueOf(exam_list_spinner.getSelectedItem()),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this, SpeedTestActivity.class);
                        SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                  });
    }



    //getting content from preferences
        public String getFromPreference(String variable_name)
        {
            String preference_return;
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            preference_return = preferences.getString(variable_name,"");

           return preference_return;
        }


        //check connection
        public boolean isOnline_downloadList() {
            ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                //sending request for login
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(getFromPreference("student_code"));



                return true;
            }

          //alert box to show internet connection error
            AlertDialog.Builder Internet_Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this);
            // set title
            Internet_Alert.setCancelable(false);
            Internet_Alert.setTitle("Attention!");
            Internet_Alert.setMessage("This application requires internet connectivity, no internet connection detected");
            Internet_Alert.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    onQuitPressed(); 
                }
            });

            Internet_Alert.create().show();
            return false;
        }

        //to remove application from task manager
        public void onQuitPressed() {

            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        }



        //===================================================================================================================================
        //sending student code to server to get exam list
        //===================================================================================================================================
        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{


            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData(params[0]);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.i("response: ", responseBody);
                //processResponce(responseBody);
                //going to next activity
                xmlContent=responseBody;
                parse_ExamList();
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

            }

            public void postData(String student_code) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://icaerp.com/AndroidDataService/dataServiceAndroid.asmx/login");

                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this);
                  final String url_first = preferences.getString("URLFirstPart","");
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_first+"ExamList");

                try {
                    // Data that I am sending
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StudentCode", student_code));
                    //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", passwrd));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    Log.d("result", responseBody);
                } 
                catch (Throwable t ) {
                    //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),""+t,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Error Time of Login",t+"");
                } 
            }
        }
        //===================================================================================================================================
        //END sending EmailAddress and Password to server 
        //===================================================================================================================================

        // function to populate SPINNER with exam list from xml
                    void parse_ExamList()
                    {

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                        //String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xmlContent); // getting DOM element

                        //count_questions=2;

                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_EXAMSET);
                        // looping through all item nodes <item>
                        for ( int i = 0; i < nl.getLength();i++) {


//                      while(counter< nl.getLength())
//                      {
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            //map.put(KEY_EXAMSET, parser.getValue(e, KEY_EXAMSET));
                            map.put(KEY_SETID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
                            map.put(KEY_SETNAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));
                            //Log.i("Set ID: ", parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
                            //Log.i("Set Name: ", parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));

                            menuItems.add(map);
                        }


                    }

                    // add items into exam list spinner dynamically
                    public void addItemsOnExamListSpinner()
                    {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("Speed Test 150(min) PO Set-01");

                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        exam_list_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    }


}
```

This is the **layout file**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SpeedTestExamNameActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/speed_choose_exam"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/speed_examlist_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/speed_exam_details_button"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/speed_examlist_spinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/details" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speed_username_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**What should I do to populate the Spinner from the Arraylist returned by the XML parsing method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a workaround by changing my code xml parsing code to this:

```
void parse_ExamList()
{

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xmlContent); // getting DOM element

    //list object to populate spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_EXAMSET);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for ( int i = 0; i < nl.getLength();i++) {



    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    //map.put(KEY_EXAMSET, parser.getValue(e, KEY_EXAMSET));
    map.put(KEY_SETID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
    map.put(KEY_SETNAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));
    //adding items to spinners
    list.add("("+parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID)+") "+parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));
    menuItems.add(map);
    }

    //populating the spinner with the list items
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    exam_list_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
```

But the problem is that, both the id and name are getting displayed in the spinner, I just want to show the name and hide the id while displaying. But later I will require the id with the selected name

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can go about doing it.

First, create a POJO `MyObject`, which has the 2 fields **KEY_SETID** and **KEY_SETNAME** and its related `getter/setter`. Override the `toString()`, to return `KEY_SETNAME`, as you want to display this as the item name in the `Spinner`.

Then create an `ArrayList` of your `MyObject`, from the `HashMap` you populated by parsing your XML.

Then using the sample code snippet below, populate data in your `Spinner`.

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerSpcial);
ArrayList<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); // This is actually the list created from the HashMap
ArrayAdapter<MyObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ObjectName>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now to get the item selected, use the below code.

```
MyObject selectedItem = (MyObject) s.getSelectedItem(); // Object which was selected.
selectedItem.getKEY_SETID(); // This will give you the ID of the item selected. Do whatever you wish with to do.
```

Try it out and let me know, if you're stuck up anywhere.

**Update:-**

Your POJO will be like this.

```
public class MyObject {
    private String KEY_SETID;
    private String KEY_SETNAME;

    public String getKEY_SETID() {
        return KEY_SETID;
    }

    public void setKEY_SETID(String kEY_SETID) {
        KEY_SETID = kEY_SETID;
    }

    public String getKEY_SETNAME() {
        return KEY_SETNAME;
    }

    public void setKEY_SETNAME(String kEY_SETNAME) {
        KEY_SETNAME = kEY_SETNAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.KEY_SETNAME; // Value to be displayed in the Spinner
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the process?

Comment: what part of the process are you stuck at? Because I've explained it in a pretty detailed manner.

Comment: I want to know the requirement of the POJO

Comment: it should be the POJO you want to have. A java object with just 2 fields.

Answer (score 2):

Tip:Try to make the code simple and working.So first,in your parsing function instead of adding a `HashMap` to the `ArrayList` .. take two arraylists and these `ArrayList`s should be declared at a class level.Correspondingly,fill both `ArrayList`s and fetch them at `Spinner` click.So your `Activity` code stands:

```
    public class SpeedTestExamNameActivity extends Activity {

        Spinner exam_list_spinner;
        Button  detailsBtn;
        TextView showUser;
    String full_name;
    ArrayList<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> menuKeys = new ArrayList<String>();

    //variables to get response from server
    String responseBody;

    //variables required for parsing the XML
    String xmlContent=null;

     // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_EXAMSET = "ExamSet"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_SETID = "SetId";
        static final String KEY_SETNAME = "SetName";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed_test_exam_name);

        //checking internet connectivity to download list
        isOnline_downloadList();

        //Showing user full name after login
        full_name=getFromPreference("user_name");
        //textview to show user name
        showUser=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.speed_username_textView);
        showUser.setText("Welcome, "+full_name);
        //spinner
        exam_list_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.speed_examlist_spinner);
        //adding items to spinners
        addItemsOnExamListSpinner();

        // onclick details button
        detailsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speed_exam_details_button);
        detailsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this,                      
                                "Exam List Spinner: "+ 

    String.valueOf(exam_list_spinner.getSelectedItem()),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //here you get the menuKey too
    Toast.makeText(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this,                      
                                    "Exam List Spinner Key: "+ menuKeys.get(exam_list_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this, SpeedTestActivity.class);
                        SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                  });
    }



    //getting content from preferences
        public String getFromPreference(String variable_name)
        {
            String preference_return;
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            preference_return = preferences.getString(variable_name,"");

           return preference_return;
        }


        //check connection
        public boolean isOnline_downloadList() {
            ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                //sending request for login
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(getFromPreference("student_code"));



                return true;
            }

          //alert box to show internet connection error
            AlertDialog.Builder Internet_Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this);
            // set title
            Internet_Alert.setCancelable(false);
            Internet_Alert.setTitle("Attention!");
            Internet_Alert.setMessage("This application requires internet connectivity, no internet connection detected");
            Internet_Alert.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    onQuitPressed(); 
                }
            });

            Internet_Alert.create().show();
            return false;
        }

        //to remove application from task manager
        public void onQuitPressed() {

            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        }



        //===================================================================================================================================
        //sending student code to server to get exam list
        //===================================================================================================================================
        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{


            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData(params[0]);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.i("response: ", responseBody);
                //processResponce(responseBody);
                //going to next activity
                xmlContent=responseBody;
                parse_ExamList();
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

            }

            public void postData(String student_code) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://icaerp.com/AndroidDataService/dataServiceAndroid.asmx/login");

                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SpeedTestExamNameActivity.this);
                  final String url_first = preferences.getString("URLFirstPart","");
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_first+"ExamList");

                try {
                    // Data that I am sending
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StudentCode", student_code));
                    //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", passwrd));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    Log.d("result", responseBody);
                } 
                catch (Throwable t ) {
                    //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),""+t,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Error Time of Login",t+"");
                } 
            }
        }
        //===================================================================================================================================
        //END sending EmailAddress and Password to server 
        //===================================================================================================================================

        // function to populate SPINNER with exam list from xml
                    void parse_ExamList()
                    {



                        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                        //String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xmlContent); // getting DOM element

                        //count_questions=2;

                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_EXAMSET);
                        // looping through all item nodes <item>
                        for ( int i = 0; i < nl.getLength();i++) {


//                      while(counter< nl.getLength())
//                      {

                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            //map.put(KEY_EXAMSET, parser.getValue(e, KEY_EXAMSET));
                            menuKeys.add( parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
                            menuItems.add( parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));
                            //Log.i("Set ID: ", parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
                            //Log.i("Set Name: ", parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));


                        }


                    }

                    // add items into exam list spinner dynamically
                    public void addItemsOnExamListSpinner()
                    {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("Speed Test 150(min) PO Set-01");

                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, menuItems);
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        exam_list_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    }


}
```

**Note:** Simple replace will do.I have only changed code in `detailsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` and your `parseExamList()` and just declared two `ArrayLists` at the class level.try it and see if you get two Toasts on Clicking details button before launching the new activity.

**UPDATE:** i assume that you've followed the [android hive tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) for parsing XML.Just change the `getValue` function with this in your `XMLParser` class:

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
```

But in case you're not following that.. then following that tutorial to build the parser would solve your issue.Insha Allah.If i have helped you to reach a solution then please mark it as an answer

Comment: menuKeys.put(KEY_SETID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
menuItems.put(KEY_SETNAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));  Here i am getting an error like: The method getValue(Element, String) in the type XMLParser is not applicable for the arguments (Element, String)

Comment: sorry i missed that change over there.. see the change of code in `parseExamList()` .. changed to `menuKeys.add( parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID)); menuItems.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));`.Hope that solves your issue Insha Allaah

Comment: Still getting this error: The method getValue(Element, String) in the type XMLParser is not applicable for the arguments (Element, String) for menuKeys.add( parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID));
                        menuItems.add( parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));

Comment: Its working, but the spinner is showing only 1 tem from the XML file, whereas there should be 3 items in the spinner

Comment: I also do not want the position of the spinner item selected, but I want the parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETID) value

Comment: `menuKeys.get(exam_list_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())` try to understand.Thats **EXACTLY** what you are getting.. you are getting the Key which you added not 0,1,2,3...

Comment: You need to set breakpoints in the code in the for loop and see why only one arraylist item is added.We do not have your XML so i cant tell.. your issue is solved.

Comment: But why is only 1 item showing up in the spinner when the XML has 3 items?

Comment: did you check setting breakpoints in that place ? is the `ArrayList` having only one item added or does it have 3 items?

Comment: tell me is it showing just this:`Speed Test 150(min) PO Set-01`

Comment: see the edit i changed a single variable in the fourth line from the last.. check it.. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15404595/revisions and this is an end to your issue.Inshallah..finally

Comment: Now its not even populating the spinner

Comment: theres something more to it than meets the eye.. are you sure thats all the code which you are using without alterations?

Comment: yup dude! I am using the same code. But I think the method public void addItemsOnExamListSpinner() might not be used. I have done a workaround but its not full proof. You may take a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15406954/1627599

Comment: well i gave a better solution than the workaround.. you can roll back to the last change which i told you,which was showing single item and put breakpoints and debug to find the problem.Its all clear from my end.

Answer (score 1):

```
Spinner spinnerLocation;
spinnerLocation = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);
    ArrayList<String> locationArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        locationArray.add("value "+i);
    } 
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locationArray);
            locationAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerLocation = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);
            spinnerLocation.setAdapter(locationAdapter);
            spinnerLocation.setAdapter(locationAdapter);
            spinnerLocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                int count=0;
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
                    System.out.println("whatever you wanna do");


                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"inside no item selected ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is spinnerLocation = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);?

Comment: The array list which you are using is different from mine. Where should I put this code? How should I use it?

Comment: i have used mine array . you can simply use your ArrayList , locationArray you can replace by your own array

Comment: your arraylist is like this: ArrayList<String> locationArray = new ArrayList<String>(); But mine is like this: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: @kittu88 : Hashmap<String,String> , you might be wanting only one of the String , store the desired String in locationArray

Comment: The way you are using your ArrayList, I can not use it in the same way. If I pass my ArrayList in place of yours, ide is asking me to change my ArrayList

Comment: Actually, I want the id and the name, which makes two strings, I have to show the name in the spinner, but the id will be required while picking up the selected item from the spinner

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26144/discussion-between-hussain-akhtar-wahid-and-kittu88)